# Concept : Does Handlers also execute network request sequentially as like AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-handler

Hello As you know that `AsyncTask` by default run your network request sequentially until you use `Executor`.

Does Handlers also execute network request sequentially ? If not then how to run them parallel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I got to know handlers also do sequentially because it process the message from queue one by one.

If you create a separate thread and do different network task then use looper thread then you get parallism.